# How to use regex in filename during diff in bash?

Tags: regex, bash, diff

I try to diff two files in bash:

```
$ diff file-1-random-name file-2-random-name
```

This works, now I need to make it more generic because the random-name will always be different.

I tried something like this:

```
$ diff file-1-* file-2-*
```

But this will take the `*` hardcoded in the file name. How can I use a regex pattern (like just a *) in the filename using my diff command?

Comment: I suggest making a little script, finding the two files first (by find or something else), saving the filenames in vars,  then do the diff.

Comment: That does *not* make the `*` hardcoded. It will be expanded by the shell to the list of matching files; but if there are no matching files (and you don't have `nullglob` or other non-default options active) the expansion will be the wildcard string itself.

Answer (score 1):

In general for such things you have to do a loop, an explicit loop in the shell or a loop hidden inside a script that you've written and you are using

As a simple solution you can adapt what follows, that is not checking for missing files etc

```
for f1 in file-1* ; do
    f2=${f1/file-1/file-2}
    printf "Comparing %s with %s:\n" "$f1" "$f2"
    diff -options "$f1" "$f2"
done
```

in the above we used parameter editing to find the name of the second file.

Comment: This is for when file-1 and file-2 have the same random name attached.  Looking at OP's question, I thought OP wanted to compare file-1 files with _each_ file-2 file.  If so, then you could do basically this, but with a nested for loop instead of changing the name from file-1 to file-2.

Comment: @TylerMarshall I answered according to my understanding.  If an answer were written according to your understanding and then accepted I'll stand corrected

Comment: That wasn't meant as a correction.  Really I wanted OP to read and make sure it's what he wanted. We'll see _if_ he comes back here to accept any answers. 0:)